# Referencing range of IP addresses

Tags: python

I am trying to specify a range of addresses that will be set every time an API is called. For the example below, when `api` is referenced, I would like it to hosts in the range to a list, and not just one as it currently does.

```
api = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://user:pass@192.168.0.1:8442/")
```

Generating the addresses seems straightforward enough, but I am unsure how to store it so that when `api` is reference, it's sends to every host, e.g. 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.100 and not just one.

```
for i in range(100):
    ip = "192.168.0.%d" % (i)
    print ip
```

I would also like to be able to specify the range, e.g. 192.168.0.5 - 192.168.0.50 rather then incrementing from zero.

**Update:** The API does not handle a list very well so the solution need to be able to parse the list. Might this simply require a second `for` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a different range:

```
for i in range(5,51):
    ip = "192.168.0.%d" % (i)
    print ip
```

Not sure what you mean by setting multiple. That for loop is doing that for you. If you're talking about saving references of your api, you can also throw those into a list.

```
api = []
for i in xrange(5,51):
    ip = "192.168.0.%d" % (i)
    api.append(xmlrpclib.ServerProxy("http://user:pass@" + ip))
```

Comment: Thanks, evidently this API does not directly support list usage. Is there a way to parse each item in the API or would that require another `for` statement to iterate through each item in the list and do something with it?

Comment: Even if there was something built in to parse each item in the api list, it would still be traversing that list. A for loop shouldn't be any slower. Sorry, if that's not what you're asking.